# Filling out page with tabular (width and height) with evently

Tags: margins, tabularx

I'm trying to make sticky labels with LaTeX. I thought this would be pretty simple because of LaTeX's nice support of absolute units, but it turned out to be quite difficult. This is the specification of the label paper:

- Left and right margin: 0mm
- Upper and lower margin: 8mm
- Label height: 25mm
- Label width: 52mm
- Inner label margin: 2mm

That's 11 rows and 4 columns of labels. The label will contain just text. Here's what I've got to so far:

```
\documentclass[portrait,a4paper,danish,oneside,final,10pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\geometry{hoffset=0mm,
          hmargin=0mm,
          vmargin=8mm,
          footskip=0mm,
          papersize={210mm,297mm},
          total={210mm,297mm}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2mm}

\newcommand{\labeltext}{\textbf{M\&M} er en sød vin lavet på hyben plukket ved Vemmingbund Strand i Sønderjylland. Vinen produceres.}

\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X|X|X}\hline
\labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext \vfill \\%[\mylabelheight]
\labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext \vfill \\%[\mylabelheight]
\labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext \vfill \\%[\mylabelheight]
\labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext \vfill \\%[\mylabelheight]
\labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext \vfill \\%[\mylabelheight]
\labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext \vfill \\%[\mylabelheight]
\labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext \vfill \\%[\mylabelheight]
\labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext \vfill \\%[\mylabelheight]
\labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext \vfill \\%[\mylabelheight]
\labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext \vfill \\%[\mylabelheight]
\labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext & \labeltext \vfill \\%[\mylabelheight]
\hline
\end{tabularx}%
\end{document}
```

This is almost correct. However, the table cells don't expand their height to fit the paper (this is, bottom row should touch the bottom margin).

Also, I can't figure out how to get an upper and lower margin of 2mm inside each cell. I tried using `\vspace{2mm}`, but that produces a much larger space than requested.

I tried posting a picture of the result, but I'm not allowed to at the moment. Sorry.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can include the image with the button; just remove the `!` in front of the string you get (`![text][1]`). A user with enough rep will put back the `!` for you. You should also have a look at the `labels` package.

Comment: I heartily second @egreg 's suggestion: take a look at the `labels` package.

Comment: @egreg: I'll do that next time, thanks!

I looked at the `labels` package, but from what I understood from the manual, it only works for ond brand of labels (unless I modified the code itself, which I didn't have the courage to do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't take this too seriously. But, hey, it works!

Idea borrowed (or stolen?) from the TeXbook, Exercise 21.8.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{palatino,microtype}

\geometry{margin=0mm}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\labeltext}{%
  \textbf{M\&M} er en sød vin lavet på hyben plukket ved Vemmingbund
  Strand i Sønderjylland. Vinen produceres.}

\fboxrule=0.2pt
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
\parindent=0pt

\newsavebox{\danbox} 

\begin{document}
\sbox\danbox{%
  \fbox{%
    \vbox to 25mm{
      \hsize=52mm \leftskip=2mm \rightskip=2mm
      \vfill\labeltext\vfill
    }%
  }%
}

\hbox to\hsize{\cleaders\vbox to \vsize{\cleaders\copy\danbox\vfil}\hfil}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to repeat a box as many times as needed. First of all we build it (with low level commands, in order to have maximum control) and store it in a save bin; by setting `\fboxsep` to `-\fboxrule` we ensure that the frame will not add to the height and width of the box. The box itself has a width of 52mm and a height of 25mm (the `\vfill` at the end will avoid any additional depth due to characters with descenders, as there's no text at the bottom, but glue).

Now the fun begins.

1. With `\hbox to \hsize` we tell TeX to build a box as wide as the page.
2. `\cleaders<material>\hfill` will fill the width with copies of `<material>`, pushing them close to each other and adding space to both sides to finish the filling.
3. Our `<material>` will be exactly 52mm wide, so four columns, with 1mm of white space on both sides (A4 paper is 210mm wide).
4. Now we specify the `<material>`: it's a `\vbox to \vsize{...}` so it will fill all the page height.
5. For filling it we do exactly the same: `\cleaders\copy\danbox\vfil` (we must use `\copy` rather than `\usebox` that would start horizontal mode). A4 paper is 297mm high, so eleven rows will be accommodated, leaving 11mm on both ends.

That's it. :)

Comment: Now it's me who is glad of still having one vote left.